# must be non-nullable in order to use as parameter 'T'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first

I am trying to create a Code First class with my own object types and get this error:

> `.MTObject'` must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   '`System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.StructuralTypeConfiguration<TStructuralType>.Property<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TStructuralType,T>>)`'

Is there a way to declare my class property to get past this error?

Code is below:

```
// Simple Example

public class MTObject
{
    public string Object { get; set; }

    public MTObject()
    {

    }
}

public class Person
{
    public decimal Id { get; set; }

    //public string Name { get; set; }

    public MTObject Name { get; set; }

    public Int32 Age { get; set; }
}

public class PersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonConfiguration() : base()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("ID").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("NAME").IsOptional();
        Property(p => p.Age).HasColumnName("AGE").IsOptional();
        ToTable("Person");
    }
}

public class PersonDataBase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public PersonDataBase(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

// End Simple EXample
```

Comment: Is this .net? Whatever, please tag question with language tag (and maybe remove one of the less relevant tags like "compiler-errors")

Answer (score 3):

In order to get this line compiling...

```
Property(p => p.Age).HasColumnName("AGE").IsOptional();
```

...you need to make the `Age` property nullable:

```
public Nullable<Int32> Age { get; set; }
```

(or `public int? Age { get; set; }`)

Or you cannot specify the property as optional and need to use it as a required property.

**Edit**

My answer above is wrong. That's not the reason for the compiler error. But the `Age` property must still be nullable if it is supposed to be *optional*, i.e. allow `null` values.

**Edit 2**

In your model `MTObject` is a complex type (not an entity) because by convention EF cannot infer a primary key property. For a complex type you can map the nested properties as:

```
Property(p => p.Name.Object).HasColumnName("NAME");
```

(assuming that you actually want to specify the column name for the `Object` property) Using is `IsOptional()` is not necessary because `string` properties are optional by default.

Comment: Plus, `Name` is a reference type; it doesn't map directly to a SQL type, so that should be a navigation property. It's then always optional.

Comment: That's really not the problem here. The problem is that the database doesn't know what `MTObject` is. It needs to be a value type or string...

Comment: @Tejs: Yes, you're right. A navigation property or a complex type which I was assuming in my Edit 2 above.

Answer (score 3):

just to help other people

in this case just change

```
Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("NAME").IsOptional();
```

to

```
Property(p => p.Name.Object).HasColumnName("NAME").IsOptional();
```

Answer (score 0):

"non-nullable" is not the important part of that error message.  The important bits are "must be a value type".  ("non-nullable" is just a modifier to "value type")

Try

```
public struct MTObject
{
    public string Object { get; set; }
}

public struct Person
{
    public decimal Id { get; set; }

    //public string Name { get; set; }

    public MTObject Name { get; set; }

    public Int32 Age { get; set; }
}
```

(Note keyword `struct` instead of `class`)

Comment: Are you sure it's because of Person and not because `Name` property? ;)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: No I'm not sure.  The important thing though is that the data passed in needs to be a value type.

Comment: Double-check the error. It's about `MTObject`. What can't be a reference type is the optional column mapped to a property of type `MTObject`. This is `Name` property can't be optional.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: So I've suggested making `MTObject` a value type.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't read that you made "MTObject" a `struct`. BTW, `Person` could still be a `class`. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I changed it in response to your first comment.  So you might well have been looking at a version of my answer that didn't have it.

Comment: An entity (`Person`) cannot be a `struct`, it must be a `class`. The reason for the compiler error is that all other overloads of `Property(...)` are more special and do not match. So the compiler tries the least specialized version which has a `struct` constraint on `T`. But the problem is not solved by making `MTObject` a `struct` because it is not a primitive type that SQL understands (`Guid` would be a `struct` that works). It would compile but throw a runtime exception. `MTObject` is a complex type (in the EF sense) and as such it must be a `class`.

Comment: @Slauma I believe the source of the problem is OP thinks that an association can be optional. If you don't say it's "required", association will be optional. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: There is no association in this model. `MTObject` is a *complex type* (just a bag of properties that gets embedded as a bunch of columns (only `Object` in the example) into the same table with `Person`), not an entity that represents another table.

Comment: @Slauma Who knows. You think that because OP is trying to map `MTObject` as a regular column, but maybe he does that because he doesn't know how to map associations... we've few details from the OP about the context...

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  I am still trying to figure out how to map the generic object to the fields.                     Specifically:  
        Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("NAME").IsOptional();
Want to say this: Property(p => p."NAME") ....   I do not want to tie the property to a specific class member.